# Style MUI component but have it's style overwritten by passed ThemeProvider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themeprovider

I want to style my custom React/MUI components by default, but still have the parent MUI `ThemeProvider` be able to override my styles.

For example, let's say that I have a Button that is green by default (styled in my code), but it should be able to have the colour overridden by a default theme passed down via `ThemeProvider`.

I can't seem to find anyway to do it as any styling I apply in my component becomes the default as it's the last in the CSS/styling tree.

Comment: How are you styling your components? Is it with a css/scss file? Or using the style object provided by MUI?

Comment: I've tried using the MUI styled object, applying a class and using the style/sx props - all of these take precedence over the ThemeProvider.

Comment: Your theme provider has a theme attribute? https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced

Comment: It is very unfortunate, that this question has no answer, because it actually a very fundamental topic in regards to material-ui! Have you figured it out what's the best solution or do you use !important in the theme etc.? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find much information in the documention or github issues about that topic — I can just tell you how to cope with the situation and how it works currently in v5.

It seems like the priority is as follows:

`sx` > `styled()` > theme

ie. `sx` has the highest priority.

At first it seems quite strange that you cannot overwrite something with your theme, but on the other hand you'd also like to be able to overwrite the theme with `sx` occasionally. So to me the priority makes sense.

You should not use `!important` in the theme if possible, because it prevents `sx` and `styled()` from doing its job.

What you'd do is ship reusable components unstyled (no `styled()` or `sx`) and style them via the theme.

Perform the colorization in the theme. Width, height, margins and paddings you can also define via `styled()` and/or `sx` if you don't need to change those in the theme.